# React media player multicolor progressbar

Tags: reactjs

I need to make multi color progress bar in react media player. I mean, when i click play on the video, the progress bar has to change the color after specific points. Currently it has only one color, the styles are below

```
@include -range-track(webkit) {
    background: {
      image: linear-gradient($track-lower-color, $track-lower-color);
      size: inherit;
      repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  }
```

Can someone help me to make the progress bar colorful?

Answer (score 1):

If you keep setting state as progress bar width changes, the render function is called each time, allow you to provide custom color for each range of percent.

```
class ColorBar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    width: 10
  }

   colorSwitch = (width) => {
    if(width >= 10 && width < 20) {
        return 'red'
    }
    if(width >= 20 && width < 50) {
        return 'orange'
    }
    if(width >= 50 && width < 100) {
        return 'yellow'
    }
    return 'green'; // default for < 10 and >= 100 
  }

  getStyle = () => {
    return {
        backgroundColor: this.colorSwitch(this.state.width),
      width: this.state.width,
      height:50,
    }
  }

  changeSize = () => this.setState({ width: this.state.width+10})

  render() {
    return <div>
            <div style={this.getStyle()} />
            <button onClick={this.changeSize}>Change size </button>
          </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ColorBar />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/51fyvzob/

Comment: Thanks, but I need to make it for media player, and the width is changing automatically. Only thing I need is to make the progress bar to change his color on specific points. I can provide a code of the whole component, but it's too long. Can you advice something about it?

Comment: You'll have something like an onProgress callback in your media player ? Can you provide the name of the media player package ?

Comment: Ok check the onProgress callback, in that method use setState with your progress as I made for width and proceed as the snippet

Comment: Can you wright me specific file in that player? Cause I'm not sure where to put the changes